# How to receive an sms in a desktop pc?

Tags: sms

I am stuck in the midst of a project. The project requires that a desktop pc must receive an sms sent from a mobile phone. How can I accomplish this? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean the software side, or the hardware side?

Comment: @omnibrain both..I am new in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a GSM Modem like [this one](http://www.amazon.de/Gigaset-L36880-N8610-A102-Siemens-Terminal-GSM-Modem/dp/B0009V968C) to the serial port. It acts like a mobile phone with its own SIM card. I'm sure there are other products for USB.

On the software side, you can check for SMS messages by talking with AT commands to the device. I've done that in Perl and in .NET "manually", but maybe there are some out-of-the-box solutions.

Answer (score 1):

i know (and have used) 2 ways to do this.

The quick, dirty and hacky way is to buy a mobile phone and connect it to your PC with a serial cable, then use old fashioned AT commands to control the phone (including listening for new SMS messages). 
Many older Nokias support this, though it's not hugely well documented - this is about the best resource I found: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AT_Commands.
There are many exciting ways this can fail - you have to keep the phone charged, and in a data centre, reception is often pretty poor.

The alternative is to talk to a mobile aggregator (Google for likely candidates in your area). These are companies that can set up SMS short codes, and have APIs for forwarding the messages to you; APIs vary between the providers. This is usually fairly expensive - shortcodes cost money, sending and receiving SMS messages costs money, and the aggregator may not have deals with countries you care about. Caveat emptor, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need a library to send/receive the AT commands to and from the modem.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/phonesmsrecv.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This software](http://smsenabler.com) can help you. It uses a GSM/3G modem attached to a PC. It can store incoming SMS messages in a database, save to files, forward them to a webserver, in real-time.
(A 3g/gsm modem has a SIM card and therefore has its own phone number to which sms messages can be sent)